# Smartwatch2 Button in notification

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

In  the Sony Smartwatch2, is there a way to have custom images in the notifications? I wish to have custom image background along with two buttons on it while notifying, just like in call handling app. can it be achieved with the Control API?

Answer (score 0):

Current SmartWatch2 API doesn't allow customizing layout of notifications. You can only customize notification icon and text.